# Why this orion subscription don't works as I want?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have the following subscription in orion 1.2.1:

```
curl  --include \
      --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --request POST \
      --data-binary '{
                       "description": "subscription",
                       "subject": {
                         "entities": [
                           {
                             "idPattern": "event-.*",
                             "type": "Event"
                           }
                         ],
                         "condition": {
                           "attrs": [
                              "IdEvent",
                              "mFlag"
                           ],
                           "expression": {
                             "q": "mFlag>0"
                           }
                         }
                       },
                       "notification": {
                         "attrsFormat":"legacy",
                         "http": {
                             "url" : "http://localhost:5050/notify"
                         },
                         "attrs": [
                            "IdEvent"
                         ]
                       }
                     }' \
      'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions'
```

When I send an entity update like this one:

```
curl --include \
     --request PATCH \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data-binary '{
                       "mFlag":{
                          "value":"5",
                          "type":"int"
                       }
                    }' \
                    'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/event-2/attrs'
```

Orion is not notifiying and it is making me crazy don't know what is wrong. Any idea?

When I remove this part of the subscription:

```
"expression": {
   "q": "mFlag>0"
}
```

it works but I need it to notify when any attribute is changed and the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Try updating with `"value": 5` (i.e. without `"` surrounding `5`)

Comment: it Works! but In my use scenario where cepheus send this value to orion it don't work any idea to solve it (I always declare this value as int in all the configs). Thanks you so much for the help.

Comment: I made a mother question so the cepheus cep developer could see it and give us his point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100704/why-cepheus-dont-send-int-without-quotes-to-orion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in NGSIv2 `"5"` is a string, not a number. Thus, in order to make the `"q": "mFlag>0"` filter works as expected, use the following update:

```
curl --include \
     --request PATCH \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data-binary '{
                       "mFlag":{
                          "value":5,
                          "type":"int"
                       }
                    }' \
                    'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/event-2/attrs'
```