# Why cepheus don't send int without quotes to orion?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

In this question I have a problem that the orion conditions were not satisfied but it was solved by removing the quotes on the especial value [Why this orion subscription don't works as I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076588/why-this-orion-subscription-dont-works-as-i-want)

The new problem is that when I process an event with cep that calculates the mFlag int attribute it send it to orion but apparently it is send with the quotes (same problem as described in the related question posted before) because the orion entity is changed but the notification is not triggered.

The cepheus cep config out is like this one:

```
"out":[
    {
      "id":"algo",
      "type":"Event",
      "brokers":[
        {
          "url":"http://localhost:1026" //orion
        }
      ],
      "attributes":[
         { "name":"IdEvent", "type":"int" },
         { "name":"mFlag", "type":"int" }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Is this problem of the cepheus cep or it is a orion bug not interpreting the type of the attribute in the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have hit an incompatibility in the NGSIv1 protocol implementation between Cepheus and Orion.

NGSIv1 has been well defined for its XML format (as a OMA standard), but not for its JSON version. The Cepheus team has based the JSON implementation one of the only existing document defining the JSON format of NGSIv1: the [API  Walkthough of the Orion documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/manuals/user/walkthrough_apiv1.md).

In this document, all values are exchanged (like in the XML format of the stantard) as strings. Therefore, Cepheus uses strings regardless of the type of the value.

If we were to decide to use some other representation than JSON strings for values, we would need a document (a proper specification for the NGSIv1 JSON !) defining which types can be represented as a JSON number.

Comment: well let's se if @fgalan can provide a full ngsi v1 document or comment if orion is not interpreting the type field in the conditions. Thanks for the answer

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any "formal" NGSIv1 JSON document. However, the Orion API walkthrough (https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html) and related documents in the Orion user manual could be used as "unofficial" guide. However, having said that, note that by limitations of the NGSIv1 parser used by Orion, numbers are interpreted as strings, so even if Cepheus sends `5` as attribute value using NGSIv1, Orion will interpret it as `"5"` (see https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/v1_v2_coexistence/index.html#native-json-types).

Comment: Bottom line: I'd suggest to solve the problem in the scope of NGSIv2, i.e. implement NGSIv2 in Cepheus. This would have two clear advantages: 1) the Orion parser for NGSIv2 doesn't have such limitation, 2) it is a formal document describing NGSIv2 JSON formats (in particular, this one: http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/)